# Reach Nat instance from NLB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have the config below on AWS:

1. NLB with TCP 443 listner on it
2. NAT instance in Target Group under NLB in public subnet with preconfigured iptables on it, the health check is passed
3. EC2 instance in private subnet
4. Routing table for private subnet uses NLB eni for 0.0.0.0 destination
5. Default Security Group accepts all incoming traffic from VPC and it's attached to EC2 and NAT instance

The problem is that I can't reach any external resource from the EC2, the example is below:

```
telnet 1.1.1.1 443
Trying 1.1.1.1...
telnet: connect to address 1.1.1.1: Connection timed out
```

I turned Flow Logs on NLB and NAT enis and I see, that request from EC2 is accepted by NLB's eni, but there is no request on NAT's eni.
When I change my Routing table to use eni from NAT instance, not NLB, I can reach anything I want.
How can I make reach the Internet from EC2 in private subnet using NLB's eni with NAT instance under it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an NLB for routing you're limited to NAT Gateway or NAT instance from this perspective.

If you are trying to add resilience or gain performance over multiple nodes you should instead make use of the [NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html).

One of the reasons NAT Gateways exist is they provided a scalable solution, prior to this you were limited to a single NAT instance per route table and the only way to adjust performance was to change instance type.

Comment: Thank you for response, Chris. Yes, I'm trying to make reliable solution, that wouldn't be affected in case of one NAT instance failure. I've already made Auto recovery of this NAT instance with Cloud Watch in case of problems with the underlying host, but I can't simulate this case and I'm worrying about it.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately this will only trigger if a host failure occurs. If your NAT receives traffic from resources across multiple AZs you will need to consider an AZ failure too. I have seen people use an autoscaling group with some automation to attach the EIP to the new instance before

Comment: I also thought about using Lambdas in the case of Cloud Watch alarms to recreate NAT instance and change Routing Table for using the new one, but haven't tried it yet. Maybe, later I will do it. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, yeah using Lambda will help with the automation. Let me know if you need any assistance/have questions? :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)